# (Android Studio) XML Autocomplete not working in including module

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have a project that has setup like following

```
Project
- SharedLibrary
  - APTextView
- CoreModule
  - core_module_layout_1.xml
  - core_module_layout_2.xml
  - core_module_layout_3.xml
  - ...
- ModuleA
  - module_a_layout_1.xml
  - module_a_layout_2.xml
  - ...
```

And this is the build.gradle

```
// build.gradle of CoreModule
dependencies {
    compile project(':SharedLibrary')
}

// build.gradle of ModuleA
dependencies {
    compile project(':CoreModule')
}
```

This setup **has been working for more than a year** until recently when I update to Android Studio 2.0, XML autocomplete of  **no longer works in any xml layout files in ModuleA**, this is what happen when I press ctrl+space in any ModuleA layout file

[image]

But! **still working properly in every layout files in CoreModule**, this is when I try the same in any CoreModule layout file

[image]

I already tried few things

1. Include SharedLibrary as dependency of ModuleA

`dependencies {
    compile project(':CoreModule')
    compile project(':SharedLibrary')
 }`

2. Turn of Power Save Mode
3. Invalidate Caches and Restart
4. Remove all iml files > delete everything in /.idea > restart Android Studio > rebuild

but none of them resolve this issue, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been months since I asked this question and I finally found the root cause of this issue

My **compileSdkVersion** and **support-v4 library** are not match, they were 23 and 21

Set them to be the same version resolve the issue.